# HTTP redirect site files (css, js, jpgs, etc) to HTTPS

Tags: http, redirect, https

What I'm looking into is taking all the file assets like the CSS, JS and images and see if I can redirect them. Right now you can visit both where if you visit a url `http://www.example.net/about-us/` it will redirect to `https://www.example.net/about-us/`.

```
http://www.example.net/assets/images/logo.png -> https://www.example.net/assets/images/logo.png

http://www.example.net/assets/css/style.css -> https://www.example.net/assets/css/style.css
```

A working example I have is on the Apple site is I would expect this file url to redirect me to the HTTPS version(http://images.apple.com/v/mac/home/y/images/home/imac_pro_02_large.jpg) but it doesn't. They do have the HTTPS version though (https://images.apple.com/v/mac/home/y/images/home/imac_pro_02_large.jpg).

I been told it's a nginx/browser thing and that it's normal behavior.

I hope I made sense. All my searches have come up with URLs only and doesn't address files so I'm hoping someone can clear this up for me.

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question, are you trying to write a program that outputs this result given some input? If so I suggest showing that program as well.

Comment: you want to allow users to use "http" and "https" both? It is supposed to be done on your server. You have to post how are you managing any service calls within your webserver...

Comment: @Aditya I think it's difficult to explain in text format but I'm just trying to see why when you visit the HTTP image directly it doesn't redirect to HTTPS like it would when you visit http://www.apple.com. When you visit Apple's site it redirects to HTTPS version.